# RabbitMQ: How to set up cluster?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to set up a RabbitMQ cluster on single PC.
How do I set up a **RabbitMQ** cluster?  Similar to localhost:15672

Comment: what things have you tried?

Comment: http://coding-insomnia.com/2013/02/23/clustering-rabbitmq-on-windows/ tried this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify the scope of my answer:

- By "single PC", I assume you want to run all nodes on the host OS, not in some kind of container or VM.
- Running those RabbitMQ nodes as separate Windows services is probably possible, but I don't know how to setup Windows services, so I'll skip that and only talk about starting RabbitMQ manually. Anyway, running several nodes on the same host is only relevant for development and testing purposes, thus I believe this is fine.

I'm not a Windows user, so the samples below are untested and might contain mistakes. Sorry if this doesn't work out-of-the-box.

## Step 1: Starting multiple nodes on a single host

To start multiple nodes on the same host, no matter if you plan to cluster them or not, you will have to give each node:

- a unique name;
- dedicated listening TCP ports.

To do that, you need to set several [environment variables](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#define-environment-variables). For instance, to start two nodes:

- For node 1:

  ```
  set RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit1@%COMPUTERNAME%
  set RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5672
  ```
- For node 2:

  ```
  set RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit2@%COMPUTERNAME%
  set RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5673
  ```

Each time you'll want to use `rabbitmqctl` to manage one of the nodes, you'll have to specify its name. For example, this will give you the status of node 2:

```
rabbitmqctl -n rabbit2@%COMPUTERNAME% status
```

The value of `RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT` is the AMQP listening TCP port. In this example, node 1 keeps the default AMQP port of 5672 and subsequent nodes take following ports (5673 and so on). RabbitMQ automatically computes other listening ports from those AMQP ports:

- The management UI will listen on `RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT` + 10000 (e.g. 15673 for node 2). So the URL would be something like `http://myhost:15673/`.
- Erlang distribution will be on `RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT` + 20000 (e.g. 25673 for node 2). This port is used by `rabbitmqctl` and for inter-node communication once clustered.

## Step 2: Clustering nodes

Now that you have several nodes running, you can use `rabbitmqctl` as usual to cluster those nodes:

```
rabbitmqctl -n rabbit2@%COMPUTERNAME% stop_app
rabbitmqctl -n rabbit2@%COMPUTERNAME% join_cluster rabbit1@%COMPUTERNAME%
rabbitmqctl -n rabbit2@%COMPUTERNAME% start_app
```